# how to customize colour of Windows logo

Tags: settings

I still wonder if there is any method by which we can customize the colour of Windows logo when it appears at the boot time.
I wish there could be any method but I could not find any on Google.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible and most likely will never be as the color is part of the Windows brand and Microsoft will not want people to be able to change this.